# Flask: session does not persist

Tags: flask, session

I cannot make flask set a session cookie. It doesn't show up in the cookie list and is not present in the next call

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True  # Aktiviert Debug-Modus und Logging
    CORS(app)
    app.secret_key = 'my_secret'
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_NAME'] = 'myName'
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
    app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Lax'
    app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(days=7)
    ...
    if 'session_id' not in session:
        session['session_id'] = uuid.uuid4().hex  
    session_id = session.get('session_id')
    ...
    session.modified = True
```